# Create a map with 2 slides menu to find a selection of entities

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

I dunno if somebody here can help me easily, and be sure i don't want you to lost your time.
I am realy a newbie in programmation (only studied HTLM at the end of 90's ^^), but i was always interested in. Unfortunetely, don't have a lot of time between my job, children, the "metro boulot dodo" as we say in France.

But with the covid virus, situation changed. I need to developp a cartography tool for my job, to help artisan who can be open during the confinement to be find by proximity users. 
We have a few time to do it (until next monday). That's the moment for me to jump in the code... if i can !

So, what i want to do is simple : i have a list of artisan, geolocalisated, that i want to place on a map. I can do it with a lot of tools i master on the internet. Not so hard.
But where it's more complicated, that's i want to have two slides menu for helping users to accurate their reschearch : one for selected the region, and another to selected the categorie of artisans (food, building worker, proximity services, etc).

Here an image of what it will be looked like : [clic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdUVs.jpg)

I found Leaflet on the internet, and i tried to understand in the tutorial how i can do it. 
But i am a newbie... and french ! So, that's a little hard for me to find the good way.

So, can i do my project, even if i am a newbie ?

And if that's possible, what tutorial need i to follow to learn to do it ?

Thank you so much.

Julien

Answer (score 0):

I created you a example.
https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/a1hs0qm3/

Very helpful are the tutorials from leaflet self. https://leafletjs.com/examples.html

Data:

```
var data = [
    {
    location: 'paris',
    name: 'Test 1',
    coords: [48.848220, 2.288350],
    type: 'restaurant'
  },
...
```

Function to filter markers:

```
//Create a group that contains the markers
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

function filterMarkers(){
    //delete the markers from the group
    fg.clearLayers();
  //get selected values
    var selectedplace = document.getElementById('select-place').value; 
    var selectedtype = document.getElementById('select-type').value; 

    var filtered = data.filter(function(entry){return entry.location == selectedplace && entry.type == selectedtype});

  //loop through each entry of the filtered array
  filtered.forEach(function(entry){
    //create marker with a popup
    var marker = L.marker(entry.coords).bindPopup(entry.location+" "+entry.name);
    //add to the group the marker
    fg.addLayer(marker);
  });
  //Set the View of the map that all markers are visible, without zooming in
  map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds(),{maxZoom: map.getZoom()});
}
```

Comment: Thx. I will see all that tomorrow, after a good night of sleep ^^ ! Cause now, it is just breaking my newbie's head xD !